# Selecting users,groups and site from alfresco database

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

I would like to select users,in which groups they belong to, and their sites. I want it with a single postgre sql query.

I've found  these queries, but i want them combined with join if possible.

```
select * from alf_permission

select * from ALF_AUTHORITY 

select * from ALF_CHILD_ASSOC where CHILD_NODE_NAME like ‘group%’

select * from ALF_CHILD_ASSOC where QNAME_LOCALNAME like ‘GROUP%’



select
    node_id,
    string_agg(string_value, ',')
from (
    select
        node_id,
        qname_id,
        (select local_name from alf_qname where id = qname_id) as qname_type,
        string_value
    from alf_node_properties
    where node_id in (
        select id from alf_node 
        where type_qname_id = (
            select id from alf_qname where local_name = 'person'
        )
        and qname_id in (
            select id
            from  alf_qname 
            where local_name in (
                'username',
                'firstName',
                'lastName',
                'email'     
            )
        )
    )
) alf_users
group by node_id;
```

Comment: Why are you doing it as a PostGreSQL query? Would it not be much simpler to write a very small webscript, use the Alfresco services to fetch the data, and return it via that?

Comment: My task is to get a list ot users,in which groups they are,and their sites. I am new to Alfresco and i know nothing of this "webscript" and how to write it.
I thought a simple join will do the trick, but the Alfresco database is strangely arranged.

Comment: You don't normally work with the Alfresco database directly, and it can change between releases. You're expected to work using Alfresco services instead. See [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/ws-hello-world-create.html) or [this](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html) for getting started with webscripts

Comment: Thnak you!
The thing is that i have a deadline, that is due 20:00, and now is 15:41. I dont have time to read all this and experiment with script. Is there somewhere on the net ready script that i can copy/paste?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to create webscript possibly in Java that will do this fast and efficient!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!
I put the script in Company Home > Data Dictionary > Web Scripts > org > alfresco > test

As you can see i created the "test" folder in "alfresco" folder, and in it i put these three files.

hello.get.html.ftl file

```
<table border>
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Groups</th>
    <th>Sites</th>
</tr>

<#list test as child>
<tr>
    <td>${child['username']}</td>
    <td>${child['groups']}</td>
    <td>${child['sites']}</td>
</tr>
</#list>
</table>
```

hello.get.desc.xml

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>Hello</shortname>
  <description>Polite greeting</description>
  <url>/test/hello</url>
  <authentication>user</authentication>
</webscript>
```

hello.get.js

```
var gens = search.luceneSearch("TYPE:\"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}person\"");
var a = [];

for (var i=0; i<gens.length;i++) {
 var username = gens[i].properties["cm:userName"];

 var b = [];
 var groups = people.getContainerGroups(gens[i]);
 for(var j=0; j<groups.length; j++) {
  b.push(groups[j].properties['authorityDisplayName']);
 }

 var sites = siteService.listUserSites(username);
 var g=[]
 for(var j=0; j<sites.length; j++) {
        g.push(sites[j]['shortName']);
 }

 //a.push('\n\n\n'+username+'\groups--> '+ b.join(', ') + '\nsites--> '+g.join(', '));
 a.push({
    'username' : username,
    'groups' : b.join(', '),
    'sites' : g.join(', ')
 })
}

model.test = a;
```

you can access the result in your_domain_name/alfresco/service/test/hello

Answer (score 1):

Try this query to get persons and groups

```
select 
ca.id,
ca.parent_node_id,
ca.child_node_id,
ca.qname_localname,
np.string_value
from alf_child_assoc as ca
join alf_node as child on child.id = ca.child_node_id
join alf_node as parent on parent.id = ca.parent_node_id
join alf_qname as q1 on q1.id = parent.type_qname_id
join alf_qname as q2 on q2.id = child.type_qname_id
join alf_node_properties as np on np.node_id = parent.id
where q1.local_name = 'authorityContainer'
and q2.local_name = 'person'
and np.qname_id = (select id from alf_qname where local_name = 
 'authorityDisplayName')
order by ca.qname_localname;`
```